# How to send id from dropdown populated student name in jsp?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am fetching **studentName** and **studentId** from database and populated name in database. now how to send **studentId** from jsp to servlet after selecting particular **studentName** from dropdown.
here is my code:

```
<Select name="studentDetails" id="std">  
    <c:forEach items="${stdList}" var="std">  
        <option value="1"><c:out value="${std.name}"/></option>  
     </c:forEach>  
</select>
```

Comment: request.getParameter("studentDetails") will give you studentId at server side code when you submit the form

Comment: you have to submit by button to submit the page or when u select the option

Answer (score 1):

You need to include your dropdown in the form and put its action as your servlet.

```
 <form method = "POST" action = "servletName">
     <Select name="studentDetails" id="std">  
         <c:forEach items="${stdList}" var="std">  
             <option value="1"><c:out value="${std.name}"/></option>  
         </c:forEach>  
     </select> 

   <input type = "submit" Value = "submit">
 </form>
```

In your `doPost` method of  servlet, you can retrieve parameters using,

```
  request.getParameter("studentDetails");
```

Note that you need to provide `<input type = "submit" Value = "submit">` in order to submit the form and you are using the `POST` method here. so it will call servlet's `doPost` method. `servletName` is the name of the servlet that is mapped in deployment descriptor `web.xml` as follows.

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>yourServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.YourServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>yourServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/yourServlet</url-pattern> 
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: @MaVRoSCy Yes man, actually I am editing this to give more explanation :). Posted early as it would give atleast a hint to the OP :).. Thank you for your comment and suggestion :)

Comment: So should I code like this <option value="${std.id}"><c:out value="${std.name}"/></option>

Answer (score 1):

```
<Select name="studentDetailList" id="std">  
        <c:forEach items="${stdList}" var="std">  
            <option value="1"><c:out value="${std.name}"/></option>  
         </c:forEach>  
    </select>
```

If you write code like above and calling request.getParameter("studentDetailList");
every time you will only get value '1'.

So make the option value as

```
<option value="${std.id}"><c:out value="${std.name}"/></option>
```

Then get value in page where action going as 
String value = request.getParameter("studentDetailList");
This will give you the corresponding id what you have selected.

Answer (score 0):

**First put a from and provide a destination servlet**

```
    <form method = "post" action = "destinationServlet">

        <Select name="studentDetails" id="std">  
            <c:forEach items="${stdList}" var="std">  
                <option value="1"><c:out value="${std.name}"/></option>  
             </c:forEach>  
        </select> 

    </form>
```

Now inside your servlet you can retrieve the parameters.
Have a look in this class : [ServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html)